# Event Object property names

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I see from the documentation that fullCalendar is expecting event properties like 'title', 'start', and 'end' from the JSON feed.

My feed uses different property names('name', 'evtStart', 'evtEnd').

Is there a way to specifiy these custom names so that fullCalendar knows what they are?

So I added this code to specify the name of the parameters in the JSON feed:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        startParam: 'startDateTime',
        endParam: 'endDateTime',
        events: {
            url: '../api/events/2014-01-01/2015-01-01',
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it means `events: {url: '../api/events/2014-01-01/2015-01-01',startParam: 'startDateTime', endParam: 'endDateTime'}`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) tells me this:

> The GET parameter names will be determined by the startParam and
>   endParam options. (`"start"` and `"end"` by default).

Comment: Thanks @Mooseman, I looked at the docs and edited my question.  It's still not working though...

Answer (score 1):

As sugested by @Mooseman and @MikeSmithDev you could use `startParam` and `endParam` for the start and end params.

For the title, since there is no option to change the parameter description, you can use [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/).

Consider the following JSON object:

```
{
    id: "387",
    name: "Learning PHP",
    startDateTime: "2014-09-03 13:00:00",
    endDateTime: "2014-09-03 15:00:00"
}
```

The following javascript will render the event as you need:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // set source and define start and end params
    events: {
        url: '../api/events/2014-01-01/2015-01-01',
        startParam: 'startDateTime',
        endParam: 'endDateTime',
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        // after rendering, since we don't have event.title,
        // set the event.name inside the div for the title
        element.find('.fc-event-title').html(event.name);
    }
});
```